# Screen sliding in phonegap application

Tags: cordova

I am facing strange issue in my phonegap application. The entire screen slides when user drags over the screen.

Before dragging

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap422.png

After dragging

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap422.png#1

Is it  a known issue? It is making my entire application unusable.

Comment: Is it just me or both the images are same!!

Comment: Please see in the right corner of the emulator..

Comment: did you check in android? what is your meta tag?

Comment: I haven't checked in android